# Single command/package in the preamble to achieve space between paragraphs

Tags: spacing, formatting, paragraphs, article, setspace

I was trying to figure out a way to instigate spaces between paragraphs on LaTex articles - that is, I want a gap between paragraphs

like this.

Whereas in LaTex, if you hit the enter key (I've hit it now)
it doesn't take you to a new line.

And sometimes if it does go to the next line, there is no gap between paragraphs, like this:
[image: Like this]
Instead it will look something like part of the paragraph, just starting on a new line. Again, if I want a bigger gap than one line, I can't seem to get it.

As a work around, I have been using

```
\vspace{5mm} %5mm vertical space
```

After every single line I need a space, however, this is not the most convenient way. Is there a better way to get a blank space rather than putting something at every spot you need it? For example, is there a line that can go in the preamble, so that if you hit the enter key it will leave a gap between paragraphs? What does

```
\addtolength\intextsep{5mm}
```

do? will it help? What about the setspace package? parskip package? I've seen a few questions similar to this one, but with many conflicting answers. Which is the easiest/best, not just for one line of spacing but many?

I'm looking for a single line/package in the preamble such that I don't have to type something every time I need a gap, just hit the return/enter key.

Comment: Please do yourself a big favor and study an intro-to-latex document. The posting [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/5001) should give you a few starting points. The amount of vertical whitespace between paragraphs of text is governed by the length parameter `\parskip`. As you've discovered, its default value is `0pt`. To increase it by, say, `1ex`, issue the instruction `\addtolength\parskip{1ex}` -- in the preamble, if you want the instruction's scope to be global.

Comment: Don't do anything with lengths manually, just load `\usepackage{parskip}`.

Comment: The `parskip` package (which uses the `\parskip` length) sets the space between paragraphs. So only comes into action when you leave a blank line in your source code or otherwise start a new paragraph (e.g. with `\par`, which is equivalent to a blank line, or via some environment that includes a `\par` call). `setspace` sets the space between single lines within your paragraph. The two packages have orthogonal goals. `\intextsep` changes the space between text and float objects and probably won't be of much help here.